# Help un-noobify my C++ homework

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int twoify(int num, int times)
{
    num *= 2;
    if (times > 0)
    {
        times--;
        return twoify(num, times);
    }
    return num;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int BET = 1;
    const int TIMES = 100000;
    const int CHANCE = 50;

    int wins = 0;
    int losses = 0;
    int wstreak = 0;
    int lstreak = 0;
    int cwstreak = 0;
    int clstreak = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
    {
        int num = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if (num <= CHANCE) // win?
        {
            wins++;
            cwstreak++;
            clstreak = 0;
            if (cwstreak > wstreak)
                wstreak = cwstreak;
        }
        else
        {
            losses++;
            clstreak++;
            cwstreak = 0;
            if (clstreak > lstreak)
                lstreak = clstreak;
        }

    }

    cout << "Wins: " << wins << "\tLosses: " << losses << endl;
    cout << "Win Streak: " << wstreak << "\tLoss Streak: " << lstreak << endl;
    cout << "Worst lose bet: " << twoify(BET, lstreak) << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    cout << endl << endl;
    return main();
}
```

In particular, the `twoify()` function seems noobis.  This is a martingale bet pattern, and basically every loss you double your previous bet until you win.

Comment: Although I disagree with using a return statement in your implementation of twoify, and its name (how about doubleN or similar?), I'm happy your spacing is consistent and readable.  This is VERY important to learn early.

Comment: Don't go to Las Vegas with this algorithm.  It's faster and less risky to make money by just going to work. Shifting or not.  :p

Comment: I like "Un-noobify" and look forward to seeing it in the dictionaries soon.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Agreed. The use of a betting system is the most noobish thing I see here. Or perhaps the OP is trying to prove that betting systems don't work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(betting_system)

Comment: @pavium: I thought it was "de-noobify" ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, avoid the useless recursion, turn it into iteration:

```
int twoify(int num, int times)
{
    do {
      num *= 2;
      --times;
    } while (times >= 0);
    return num;
}
```

But, you can do better (if `times > 0` is guaranteed, which would also simplify the version above by allowing you to use a `while` instead of the `do`/`while`, but, anyway...):

```
int twoify(int num, int times)
{
    return num << (times + 1);
}
```

The reason this works is that it's equivalent to multiplying num by 2 raised to the (times + 1)th power, which is what the recursive and iterative versions both do.

Answer (score 4):

```
int twoify(int num, int times) {
    return num << (times + 1);  // num * 2**(times+1)
}
```

Comment: MATH!  twoify(5,3) = 2(2(2(5))) = (2^3)*5
Grandpa, your twoify(5,0) = 10.  Should be just (times) not (times + 1).

Comment: @codebliss: you're wrong, it's times+1 if you want the function to output the same as the OP's function.

Comment: The OP's twoify(5,0) is also 10.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why twoify is a recursive method.  Maybe this was used during the class to introduce or illustrate recursion, but clearly this could be replaced by a function which multiplies num by 2^times.  This can be expressed with the exponentiation mathematical operator of the C language or, as shown in other response, by doing a left shift operation, shifting by as many bits as the exponent (the "times" argument, here)

Comment: OP wanted to "un-noobify" though.  To me that entails, among other things, eliminating excess recursion.